# Bootstrap - ¿Cómo hacer botones responsive en hero?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, grid

**Buenas!
Estoy desarrollando un sitio web con Bootstrap 5.1.3.**

Tengo un hero con un titulo y 3 botones.

La idea es que quiero que en tamaños desktop esté todo en una línea y cada uno ocupe su espacio.

Y en tamaños pequeños, que haga lo contrario: que esté uno por uno, ósea cada uno ocupe un 100% del width.

---

He intentado con el sistema grid de bootstrap, funciona pero no se alinea al centro.

Adjunto snippet de código.

```css
/* Hero Horizontal */

#lotes_body .hero-barra-horizontal {
  color: white;
  background: #78af0a !important;
  background-image: url("../img/other/loteamientos-fondo_4-v2.png");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 6em;
}

#lotes_body .hero-barra-horizontal {
  height: 6.5em;
}

#lotes_body .hero-barra_horizontal h2 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", arial;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap 5.1.3 -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>

<body id="lotes_body">
  <section class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center  hero-barra-horizontal">
    <h2>¡Empezá a invertir en tu futuro!</h2> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="quiero-un-lote.php" class="btn btn-outline-light"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-signature"></i>&nbsp;QUIERO UN LOTE</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="loteamientos.php" class="btn btn-outline-light"><i class="fa-solid fa-seedling"></i>&nbsp;VER LOTEAMIENTOS</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-light"><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>&nbsp;ENVIAR UN MENSAJE</a>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Gracias!

Comment: si lo quieres hacer con bootstrap debes usar el sistema de grid, container, row y col-lg, col-sm, etc. Si lo quieres hacer con css debes usar flexbox y mediaqueries

Comment: @HernánGarcia Gracias! Me podrías responder a mi pregunta por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con la ayuda de dos simples clases de Bootstrap podrás lograr el comportamiento deseado:

**flex-column** Hara que los elementos se posicionen uno debajo del otro en pantallas pequeñas.

**flex-row** Hara que los elementos se posicionen en linea a un costado del otro, puedes usar **flex-sm-row**, **flex-md-row**, **flex-lg-row** o **flex-xl-row** segun el punto de quiebre que necesites.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap 5.1.3 -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>

<body id="lotes_body">
  <section class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-center align-items-center hero-barra-horizontal">
    <h2>¡Empezá a invertir en tu futuro!</h2> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="quiero-un-lote.php" class="btn btn-outline-light"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-signature"></i>&nbsp;QUIERO UN LOTE</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="loteamientos.php" class="btn btn-outline-light"><i class="fa-solid fa-seedling"></i>&nbsp;VER LOTEAMIENTOS</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-light"><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>&nbsp;ENVIAR UN MENSAJE</a>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Excelente uso de clases

Comment: Mil gracias Carlos! Me salvaste la vida, tengo que entregar la web mañana. :)